# Breaking a magnet

Tags: ferromagnetism

When a bar magnet is broken into 2 pieces, we know that the 2 new pieces also become bar magnets with 2 poles. The piece corresponding to the north pole of the unbroken magnet gets a new south pole, and likewise the other piece gets a new north pole. My question is, how do these broken parts know which pole they're supposed to acquire?

My guess is that it has to do with the alignment of the so called "domains" of the ferromagnetic material that dictate which polarity each broken end will acquire, but I'm not entirely sure. Would appreciate some more insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pieces do not need to know which end should be a $+$ or a $-$ pole, the internal distribution of the dipoles is *frozen* at manufacture in the permanent magnet. What is actually frozen in are the walls, the boundaries, within which the elementary dipoles are all aligned naturally. Normally, within a single crystal there are several domains separated by walls, and within each one of these several domains the elementary dipoles of the constituent atoms are aligned.

When a soft magnet is unbiased the walls within a domain are positioned naturally so that the effective polarization of the whole crystal zero. An external bias field, unless it is exceptionally strong, cannot change the direction of these aligned dipoles within a domain, there are preferred crystalline direction for the dipole alignments, but it can move the walls between them so that effective polarization of a domain is mostly along the external bias field.

In a hard magnet the walls move with great difficulty, ie., "friction", but can be unfrozen at a temperature above the so-called Curie point at which the ferromagnet becomes a paramagnet. When placed in a bias field to align the dipoles and then cooled below the Curie temperature the walls of the evolving domains will be frozen so that the magnet becomes a permanent one. Every *macroscopic* piece of the magnet this way is aligned with the original bias field with which it was created. When you break a big magnet into smaller but macroscopic pieces they all present themselves as similarly polarized but smaller permanent magnets.

Comment: "When placed in a bias field to align the dipoles and then cooled below the Curie temperature" - do you mean "when placed in a bias field to align the dipoles *while below the Curie temperature*"?

Comment: @gs biasing starts above the Curie temperature when it is a paramagnet and then it is cooled below while still in the bias field.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're talking about, but if you mean the thing that industrial magnetizers do, they do it with everything at room temperature.

Comment: @gs I think you are talking about powder metallurgy in a polymer matrix. I was thinking about large single pieces of alloys such as the ones made out of AlNiCo, which is biased and then cooled down from 1200C. In either case, the external bias field cannot change the domain polarization, it can only move its walls.